# DataGridView stay empty even if SQL request is right

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

So, I simply need to fill a DataGridView of a WinForm with the result of a SQL request that I tried in MySQL Workbench and works perfectly.

It's not the first time I'm doing this in this particular program and all the others worked fine. However, no matter what I do, the DataGridView stays empty.

Here goes my code :

```vb
Dim BindingName As New BindingSource, ProdSet As New DataTable

    Private Sub SelectAllFacture()

        ClassConfig.Connexion.Open()

        ProdSet.Clear()

        Dim Requete As String
        Requete = "SELECT * FROM Product"

        Try
            Dim Cmd As New MySqlCommand
            With Cmd
                .Connection = ClassConfig.Connexion
                .CommandText = Requete
            End With

            Dim Adpt As New MySqlDataAdapter(Cmd)
            Adpt.Fill(ProdSet)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Autorisations.ErrorCheck(ex)
        End Try

        ClassConfig.Connexion.Close()

        BindingName.DataSource = ProdSet
        DataGridView.DataSource = BindingName

    End Sub
```

To explicit what is not shown :

- DataGridView is ... well, the DataGridView
- Autorisations.ErrorCheck(ex) calls a Sub from another class that opens a MsgBox on error (It doesn't).
- ClassConfig.Connexion is simply the connection, stored in another Class

Comment: This is a debugging problem.  Put a debug stop on the `BindingName.DataSource = ProdSet` line, when it reaches it, examine your table with your debugging tools.  If it's empty, you might be connecting to the wrong database.

Comment: Ok now this is really weird ... Cause I do have my datas in the table.

Comment: The posted code works, so I can't recreate the problem.  Is your grid really named "DataGridView"?  Usually there is a number behind it, etc.

Comment: The probleme was in the name of the binding source, I renamed mine (That was really `BindingFact`) for `BindingName` and it somehow worked ? I may have use `BindingFact` somewhere else in the program, it is entierly possible.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Filling a Dataset (prodset), make it a datatable

```
Dim prdtable as new DataTable
```

then

```
Adpt.Fill(prdtable)
BindingName.DataSource = prdtable
```

Also make sure you have either already added the correct columns to the DataGridView or set:

```
dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true
```

Comment: I mentioned in the other comment that this is absolutly right, and so I did it. However, it still doesn't work ...

Comment: Edited with new suggestion - Set AutoGenerateColumns = true

Comment: It still doesn't work ... I'm trying to find out if it's a stupid mistake but a stop show that it's triggering, however, I still get no result, not even the columns

Comment: In debugging, have you made sure the table contains any data.  Once you've set the bindingsource, also check the contents of bindingsource.datasource to make sure there really is something to display.  If the datasource contains rows, check that datagridview.columns also exists and contains what you'd expect.